# Powershell New line within function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This function lists server details withing the win32_logicaldisk class for providing information on particular servers. Providing one server the table provides all the information clearly readable, but using 10+ servers it becomes a little more complicated. Is there a way within or outside the function that provides a space for each server it picks up.

```
Function Get-DiskInfo

    {
    param ($System =".")
    $display = @{label = "Server name" ; Expression={$_.systemname}}, `
    @{label = "Drive" ; Expression={$_.DeviceID}}, `
    @{label = "Volume Name" ; Expression={$_.volumename}}, `
    @{label = "File Sytem" ; Expression={$_.filesystem}}, `
    @{label = "size (GB)" ; Expression={ [Math]::round($_.size / 1gb)}}, `
    @{label = "Free Space (GB)" ; Expression={ [Math]::round($_.freespace / 1gb)}}, `
    @{label = "Free %" ; Expression={ [Math]::round($_.freespace / $_.size * 100)}}
    Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -computername $server | format-table $display -auto
    write-host "testing"
    # THIS FUNCTION DETAILS DISK SPACE AND $% REMAINING FOR A SERVER
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle multiple servers within the function do this:

```
Function Get-DiskInfo
{
  param ([string[]]$System =@("."))

  foreach ($s in $server) {
    $display = @{label = "Server name" ; Expression={$_.systemname}}, `
    @{label = "Drive" ; Expression={$_.DeviceID}}, `
    @{label = "Volume Name" ; Expression={$_.volumename}}, `
    @{label = "File Sytem" ; Expression={$_.filesystem}}, `
    @{label = "size (GB)" ; Expression={ [Math]::round($_.size / 1gb)}}, `
    @{label = "Free Space (GB)" ; Expression={ [Math]::round($_.freespace / 1gb)}}, `
    @{label = "Free %" ; Expression={ [Math]::round($_.freespace / $_.size * 100)}}
    Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -computername $s | format-table $display -auto
    # THIS FUNCTION DETAILS DISK SPACE AND $% REMAINING FOR A SERVER
  }
}
```

However when you output formatted text from a function like this you can't really use the data from.  You can see it prettily formatted but using it programmatically - well you're back to parsing text.  I would do this:

```
Function Get-DiskInfo
{
  param ([string[]]$System =@("."))

  foreach ($s in $server) {
    Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -computername $s | Foreach {new-object psobject `
       -property @{ServerName = $_.systemname; `
                   Drive=$_.DeviceID; `
                   VolumeName=$_.volumename; `
                   FileSystem=$_.filesystem; `
                   SizeGB=[Math]::round($_.size / 1gb); `
                   FreeSpaceGB=[Math]::round($_.freespace / 1gb); `
                   FreePercent=[Math]::round($_.freespace / $_.size * 100)} `
    }
    # THIS FUNCTION DETAILS DISK SPACE AND $% REMAINING FOR A SERVER
  }
}
```

Now you are outputting objects with the data you want.  You can always use Format-Table after the function call to format the fields.  Or if you want to get real adventurous you can look into using Update-FormatData to get your custom objects to be automatically formatted by PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please expalin the param ([string[]]$System =@(".")) ?? I am new to powershell you may of noticed!  thank you for any help

Comment: That tells PowerShell that the `System` parameter should take an array of strings and if an array is not provided, PowerShell will make it an array of strings e.g. like making `-System server1` an array with one string in it (server1).

Comment: Makes sense! - Cheers for the help Keith

Answer (score 2):

Just add `""` to the end of the function. That will put a empty line at the end. 
You could even get fancy and do something along the line of:

```
Function Get-DiskInfo
{
    param ($System =".")
    write-host $system "----------------"
    $display = @{label = "Server name" ; Expression={$_.systemname}}, `
    @{label = "Drive" ; Expression={$_.DeviceID}}, `
    @{label = "Volume Name" ; Expression={$_.volumename}}, `
    @{label = "File Sytem" ; Expression={$_.filesystem}}, `
    @{label = "size (GB)" ; Expression={ [Math]::round($_.size / 1gb)}}, `
    @{label = "Free Space (GB)" ; Expression={ [Math]::round($_.freespace / 1gb)}}, `
    @{label = "Free %" ; Expression={ [Math]::round($_.freespace / $_.size * 100)}}
    Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -computername $System | format-table $display -auto
    ""
    # THIS FUNCTION DETAILS DISK SPACE AND $% REMAINING FOR A SERVER
}
Get-DiskInfo localhost
Get-DiskInfo .
Get-DiskInfo 7vm01
```

This produces the following result :

```
localhost ----------------

Server name Drive Volume Name File Sytem size (GB) Free Space (GB) Free %
----------- ----- ----------- ---------- --------- --------------- ------
7VM01       A:                                   0               0       
7VM01       C:                NTFS              80              29 36    
7VM01       D:                                   0               0       



. ----------------

Server name Drive Volume Name File Sytem size (GB) Free Space (GB) Free %
----------- ----- ----------- ---------- --------- --------------- ------
7VM01       A:                                   0               0       
7VM01       C:                NTFS              80              29 36    
7VM01       D:                                   0               0       



7vm01 ----------------

Server name Drive Volume Name File Sytem size (GB) Free Space (GB) Free %
----------- ----- ----------- ---------- --------- --------------- ------
7VM01       A:                                   0               0       
7VM01       C:                NTFS              80              29 36    
7VM01       D:                                   0               0
```

To run on a list of machines one could load the list in to a string and then iterate through the string using foreach.

```
foreach($server in $serverlist){
    Get-DiskInfo $server
}
```

Comment: In my example i use $server, this calls a list of servers 10+ your example is using the same server name. I would like to feed the function any ammount of servers and forit to place a space for each server it finds ^ the example you provided didnt work :/

Comment: Sorry correct myself, it does work! but you need to call the function for every server i have in the list it their a alternative way. For example i have a txt file with 100 servers this would be repeitive code

Comment: Ahh.. Keiths answer details one way to do that. Or you can see my update.